# Xamarin iOS ProgressView doesnt change

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin

i want to implement a UIProgressView, which is loading from 0 to 100 in 8 Seconds, but it doesent work.

Here is my Code. The ProgressView appaers right, but it doesent update them self. What is my fault?

```
public override void ViewDidAppear(bool animated)
    {
        base.ViewDidAppear(animated);

        Timer = NSTimer.CreateRepeatingScheduledTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15.0), delegate
        {
            DismissViewController(true, null);
        });

        UIView.Animate(8, () => {
            progressView.SetProgress(1.0f, true);
        });
    }
```

Comment: Your `UIView.Animate` code is correct, if you set a breakpoint on the `progressView.SetProgress` line is it being call?

Answer (score 1):

It should actually work, i've tested your code out for myself. Just make sure that the initial value of the progresbar is set to zero:

```
progresView.Progress = 0f;
```

Or in the interface builder/your designer:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I used the following to do what you are looking to do.

set progress to 0

```
progressView.Progress = 0.0f;
```

Use the Animate function with delay and animation option.

```
UIView.Animate (8, 0, UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveLinear,
    () => {
      progressView.SetProgress(1.0f, true);
    },
    () => {
      // animation complete action, 
      // instead of doing the delay above your animation just navigate away in here.
    }
);
```

I hope this helps. Cheers.